# How do I pass a regex expression without changing it?

Tags: python, regex

I have a function with a str parameter meant for regex, however whenever I pass a regular expression to that function it changes the formatting of that string, adding extra escape characters that break the expression.

I've tried sending both strings with the r in front of the string (`r'[a-zA-Z]+ \(?(?:\d ?)+\)?'`) and without with the same result.

Will I have to manually remove the extra escape characters inside the function or is there a better way?

Here's an example:

```py
>>> def function(regex=r''):  # needs to be a kwarg for the actual implementation
...     return regex
...     
>>> function("r'[a-zA-Z]+ \(?(?:\d ?)+\)?'")
"r'[a-zA-Z]+ \\(?(?:\\d ?)+\\)?'"
```

According to pycharm's debugger the actual value is even worse as it also adds extra stuff after the 'r': `'r\\'[a-zA-Z]+ \\(?(?:\\d ?)+\\)?\\'`

I was expecting the resulting string to be `r'[a-zA-Z]+ \(?(?:\d ?)+\)?'`, without the added escape characters/backslashes that end up creating a bad pattern.

Comment: if the string is represented in something like the debugger, it will show the escape characters in the representation.  But that just means that the string ` \\ ` for example is a single backslash character in the string, or ` \n ` represents a newline, not backslash n.  Are you sure your string is being modified, or just that you are looking at the representation of it

Comment: Do just `function(r'[a-zA-Z]+ \(?(?:\d ?)+\)?')`, without additional `" "`. `r' ' ` is just a syntactic sugar to avoid manual escaping. Both strings are the same. See `r'[a-zA-Z]+ \(?(?:\d ?)+\)?' == '[a-zA-Z]+ \\(?(?:\\d ?)+\\)?'` in the interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're double-wrapping your regex. Remove the extra quotes. `r` is a prefix, not part of the string.

```
function(r'[a-zA-Z]+ \(?(?:\d ?)+\)?')
```

Comment: Thanks! That would've taken me forever to notice on my own since I apparently had a different bug affecting things at the same time. Once this was cleared up the other bug became apparent and was easily solved.